# Internationalization of text that is formed by concatenating variables with constant strings

Tags: javascript, internationalization, template-literals

Different languages structure sentences differently. In english we say `White house`, while other languages use a different structure where the noun is first, and the adjective second.

When I am creating a string I concatenate a color variable with a string constant using template literals.

```
`${color} House`
```

The adjective is alway before the noun.

If it was just a constant string `White house` the translation would be straight forward in the lang.json file. How do you accurately translate a string where it is composed of variables in a specific order; or in a set spot in the string, due to other languages structuring their sentences in a different order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually do not use template strings let the i18n framework do the job - most major i18n frameworks come with an interpolation feature, like eg. in i18next:

string resource `myKey: {{color}} house` -> `i18next.t('myKey', { color: 'white' })`

https://www.i18next.com/interpolation.html

Comment: you can adapt interpolation prefix/suffix to look like template strings prefix/suffix ${}